# Facebook Linter not Picking up Open Graph Meta Tags: Tried Everything?

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-like, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I know this is a fairly common problem, the Facebook Linter is not picking up the og: meta tags that I have put up on my Wordpress 2.9 blog.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.1" <html xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-rdfa-2.xsd" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<title>
Banana Corporation, Inc. | About general WTF happening around us.
</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="MalluCars! &#8211; My Social Media Marketing Moment." />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://vadakkus.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/69f04b58_ape2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://vadakkus.com/2011/09/01/mallucars/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Banana Corporation, Inc." />
```

I have visited several forums, every conceivable support center for this, but have not gotten any solution. The fact is that even opengraph.in is not recognizing my og tags, so I must be really doing something very wrong.

I changed the doctype and html headers on advice from this forum, and removed the meta=http tag on advice of the facebook forum.

I have tried several methods of code, several plugins but nothing works. I have tried disabling all plugins, checked all .php files for any discrepancies and so on.

I have been pulling out my hair for a week or so now and this entire thing has been driving me nuts!!

Could someone please help me? I would be eternally grateful!

http://vadakkus.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to include

```
<meta property="og:description" content="some text needs to go here" />
```

Without content in og:description, all the og meta information is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://vadakkus.com/" />
```

and tell about result

Comment: No, I tried and it does not work... Sorry... Wonder if it is a problem with my theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing all the html validation errors found [here](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Does validation really matter? I haven't come across a single site that checks out completely. Even Mashable has 500+ errors!

Comment: Depends on what the validation error. Some can have an effect - like unclosed tags.